# map api in android

Tags: android

I need to use map in my Android application. There are many Android platforms. Do I need Google APIs for maps or will Map work for all platforms? I am getting an error when I change platforms from Google APIs to Android 2.2.

Comment: You should explain what error you're getting and show what code caused the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you change from google API to Android 2.2??

If you select google API it contains both jars `maps.jar` and `Android2.2 jar`.
But if you selcet Android 2.2 maps.jar will not get added.

If you want to run applicatin having google map you should run in google API and in AVD in which Google API is slected.

Dont bother about different platforms of Google API as they will usually run on different google api level.(selecting minimum in your case level 7 is preferable)

Comment: Yes , I got it that it will all Google APIs platforms .but Does Map work for only Google APIs but not for Others ???

Comment: What do you mean by not for others?

Comment: Suppose I develop an application with map in Google APIs platform and Can I run it on other platform like Android 2.2 without google APIs ???

Comment: Yes yes.. ofcourse!! it is just for emulators.. whatever Google API you develope on it will run on all android phones.But you shoud keep it in mind that you should have final release key to launch your application. You must be having Debug Key right now.

Comment: Yes I got U .I know all remaining neccesary information . I also have uploaded apk on Android market . I never faced any problem and map also work fine . Thank for corporation Mr. Harshad

Comment: thats great.. Perhaps you could help me on how to get that final release key.

Comment: Hi Harshad , Contact me on nandlal@dignizant.com

Comment: Sorry ,*Still i am not getting your reply

Comment: sorry.. Replying on ur specified mail.